# better way to create pure python lists from JSON files in python

Tags: python, json

I have a `JSON` file in `Python`. File contents are below.

```
{
    "cities": [
        "NY",
        "SFO",
        "LA",
        "NJ"
    ],
    "companies": [
        "Apple",
        "Samsung",
        "Walmart"
    ],
    "devices": [
        "iphone",
        "ipad",
        "ipod",
        "watch"
    ]
}
```

I want to create `Python` lists from this `JSON` file. I have done like below.

```
# Open JSON file in Python 
with open('test.json') as out_file:
  test_data = json.load(out_file)

# Query the output variable test_data 
test_data
{u'cities': [u'NY', u'SFO', u'LA', u'NJ'], u'companies': [u'Apple', u'Samsung', u'Walmart'], u'devices': [u'iphone', u'ipad', u'ipod', u'watch']}

# find type of test_data
type(test_data)
<type 'dict'>

# create list from test_data
device = test_data['devices']

# Check content of list created
device
[u'iphone', u'ipad', u'ipod', u'watch']
```

Now as you see the list is a `unicode list` I want it to be a pure `Python` list.

I can do like below

```
device_list = [str(x) for x in device]
device_list
['iphone', 'ipad', 'ipod', 'watch']
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does it really matter if you have `unicode` objects instead of `str` objects?

Comment: @chepner It doesn't really matter But I would like to know how to do if it really matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change the json.load to json.loads it will fix your issue. Removing any need to map.

Try this.

```
import jason
import yaml


f = open('temp.json', 'r')
json_str = f.read()

content = json.loads(json_str)

# this should remove all the unicode and return a dictionary
content = yaml.load(json.dumps(content))

content
{'cities': ['NY', 'SFO', 'LA', 'NJ'], 'companies': ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Walmart'], 'devices': ['iphone', 'ipad', 'ipod', 'watch']}

content['devices']
['iphone', 'ipad', 'ipod', 'watch']
```

Comment: It stills gives me `unicode lists`.even when I use `json.loads`

Comment: Are you on python 2? I made an edit. I think this will work for you now.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `map`

**Ex:**

```
l = [u'iphone', u'ipad', u'ipod', u'watch']
print(map(str, l))
```

*python3*

```
print(list(map(str, l)))
```

**Output:**

```
['iphone', 'ipad', 'ipod', 'watch']
```

Unicode or regular string does not make much difference

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get back a list of `unicode` objects is that JSON uses Unicode. For plain ASCII strings, it would be sufficient to simply call `str`, but for "real" Unicode, you need to encode them first.

```
>>> [str(x) for x in json.loads(u'["foo"]')]
['foo']

>>> [str(x) for x in json.loads(u'["föö"]')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> [x.encode('utf8') for x in json.loads(u'["föö"]')]
['f\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6']
```